# Arduino AltSoftSerial press enter to read/print altSerial?

Tags: serial-port, arduino

Don't know if there are any Arduino-wizards around here on StackOverflow, but I'm just gonna try and find one! I'm having issues understanding some code, and why I can't automate the process instead of pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

I'm using an RFID reader to read some tags, and using the altSoftSerial library. However, in order to print the tagID to my serial, I need to press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. And for the love of God I can't figure out why that is. Isn't it possible to check the altSerial.read for a certain ID, and print it when it appears? Cause when I print the serial automatically I just get a lot of 'FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF' noise...

```
#include <AltSoftSerial.h>

AltSoftSerial altSerial;
char txrxbuffer[255];
char get_readID[] = { 0xAA , 0x00, 0x03, 0x25, 0x26, 0x00, 0x00, 0xBB };

void setup()
{
Serial.begin(9600);
Serial.println("Hit Enter to read the RFID number");
altSerial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() // run over and over
{ 
int counter = 0;

if (Serial.available()){
    Serial.read();
    Serial.println("");
    for (counter =0 ; counter < 8 ; counter++){
      char tagID = get_readID[counter];

      altSerial.write(tagID);
    }
}
if (altSerial.available())
  Serial.print(altSerial.read(),HEX);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

seems like before reading a tag, you have to send a specific code to your rfod reader, code that you are sending in the first if; if at least one char is received on Serial (from pc), it read the char (but does not store it, it does so to clean the input buffer, so every char is a read, any char is good), and then send this code. The second if look for the answer and if present send it back to pc. So just send that code from setup() and then after every read, or look for an alternative commad that remain enabled